# Why are latches level triggered and flip flops edge triggered?

Tags: flipflop, latch, diagram

I know what it means to be edge or level triggered but considering the block diagram or logic diagram of inside of latches and flip flops I cannot see what inside them specifies this property of each, or how are they different that makes some level triggered and some edge triggered?

Can someone explain please?

Comment: When in doubt, check Wiki 1st https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)  then websearch images https://duckduckgo.com/?q=D+FF+cmos&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: That's just how we generally use the terms -- although you'll find plenty of counterexamples in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

The edge is performed by Transmission gate switches with positive feedback on the D value to isolate it by holding the charge voltage at D when Clock goes high to enable gate without o- and disable with -o using complementary drive switches with CMOS.

[image]

[Ref](https://allthingsvlsi.wordpress.com/tag/transmission-gate-based-d-flip-flop/)

Comment: Hey, err...Sunnyskyguy?...could you please add a citation or other attribution for the graphic content you included in your answer?

Comment: Ref link was in comments ehm..